# Can I declare table name with escape sequences in sqlite3?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to create a table name with escape sequences ?
like TableName:exampl's

I have EditText and it's entry like that and want to create a table  for it ,and there is no restriction for the edittext.

Comment: Please don't - you're making my head hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Or at least sqlite3 itself does not forbid this.
The following example would create the table `tbl'1`

```
create table "tbl'1"(one varchar(10), two smallint);
```

**But.**

There are several reasons why you should not do that:

- Naming tables after user input is simply not acceptable. (http://xkcd.com/327/)
- I assume that you are using a database wrapper and you do not directly access the sqlite3 file. If yes, than this solution may fail eventually.
- If you have a valid database model, there will be no need to create tables dynamically. **Insert rows for new data instead**. There you can use as much escape characters as you want.