# Android sqlite table name ' character

Tags: android, sqlite

How is it possible to add a `'` mark in an sqlite table name?

The user creates the table and I want to add the ability to use `'` mark in the table name.

```
e.g Dad's stuff
```

And what about other special characters like `(_ - / , .)` ?

I tried

```
String newlist_listname = et_NewGroceryList.getText().toString();
unrecognized token: "'s_stuff

newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\'");
unrecognized token: "'s_stuff

newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\\'");
unrecognized token: "'s_stuff 

newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "''");
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_Mom''s_stuff

newlist_listname = "'" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "''") + "'";
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_'Mom''s_stuff'

newlist_listname = "'" + newlist_listname + "'";
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_'Mom's_stuff'

newlist_listname = "'" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "'";
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_'Mom's_stuff'

newlist_listname = "'" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\\'") + "'";
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_'Mom's_stuff'

newlist_listname = "'" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "''") + "'";
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_'Mom''s_stuff'

newlist_listname = "\'" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "\'";
 syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_'Mom's_stuff'

newlist_listname = "\\'" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "\\'";
unrecognized token: "\": CREATE TABLE GL_\'Mom's_stuff\'

newlist_listname = "''" + newlist_listname.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "''";
syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_''Mom's_stuff''
```

(I also replace spaces with _)

Is there anything I have not tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare table name with escape sequences in sqlite3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205345/can-i-declare-table-name-with-escape-sequences-in-sqlite3)

Comment: Wrap it in square brackets. [Dad's stuff]

Comment: syntax error: CREATE TABLE GL_[Mom's_stuff] and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is for some sort of list-making application?

Don't create a table per list. That's bad database design. Create one table for all list entries, and use a column in that table to indicate which list they belong to -- something like this:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| list      | position | item         |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Groceries | 1        | eggs         |
| Groceries | 2        | butter       |
| Groceries | 3        | milk         |
| Hitlist   | 1        | Guido        |
| Hitlist   | 2        | Franco       |
...
```

With an index on `list`, this is just as fast -- possibly faster -- than having a table per list.

Comment: yes. When the user creates a new list item, a new record is added to the table and also a new table is created with the same name. So the main table (list) holds all the tablenames

Comment: That's what I thought. Don't do that.

Comment: I guess what you mean is that I should not use that collector table. In the listview I should show all tables, which means that collector table is not just bad design, but unnecessary also, right?
Edit: it occurs to me now, that I could store all records of all tables in just one table, and use that indicator column as "tablenames". I guess, that is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, I understand! Accept your argumentation as correct answer, however without remaking the whole database i could do sg like this: replaceAll("\'", "XYXY"), supposing the user will never type XYXY and then replace it back.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use an actual single quote in a value, you have to escape it with another quote, so you would need to modify `Dad's Stuff` to be `Dad''s Stuff` before it is inserted into the SQLite query.  In data values, Android does this for you when you supply your data to the `whereArgs` array in a `insert()`, `update()`, `query()`, or `delete()` method, but for a table name you will need to escape this yourself.

Something like `String.replace("'","''")` should do the trick.  Not sure for table names, you may need to pre-wrap the name you pass in single quotes as well, i.e. `'Dad''s Stuff'`.

Single quote (i.e. apostrophe) is really the only special case because it is the character that is used to escape all other characters in SQL statements.  In other words, I can pass a string in a SQL statement like `'(The_St/atement)'` safely because the whole thing is in single quotes.

HTH